# Como atualizar o Node.js da versão 8 para a 10 no Linux Ubuntu, via SSH?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ssh

Tentei vários tutoriais na internet antes de vir postar a dúvida aqui no StackOverflow e nenhuma dica deu certo. Meu repositório está com a versão 8 do Node e o mesmo, mesmo retirando, volta.

Preciso instalar o Node 10.

Já tentei:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs

sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs

udo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

E remove. E quando uso o tutorial da DigitalOcean que diz:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
```

E em seguida:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Volta a instalar a versão 8 e não a 10 no Node.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Boa tarde, infelizmente eu uso centOS na digitalOcean, mas não tive problemas para remover e instalar o nodejs, verifique no [Repositório Oficial nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) se algo não ajuda, la tem o passo a passo para instalaçao manual do nodejs em qualquer versão em qualquer distro linux com suporte a nodesource.

Comment: Lendo o repositório oficial, na parte de Manual installation, diz que é necessário remover o PPA antigo para então adicionar o novo, com a nova versão do node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vá até /etc/apt/sources.list.d , e verifica no arquivo node.sourcelist se possui alguma referencia ao node_8.x.

Se possuir, deleta, faz o curl para a versão 10 novamente por desencargo, apt update e depois um apt install nodejs.

Answer (score 5):

Use o modulo do npm para atualizar o node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Para atualizar para a versão mais recente (e não atual estável), você pode usar

```
sudo n latest
```

Comment: Oi @Iago Carvalho, por é, diz que o npm não existe: sudo: npm: command not found e Node tá lá instalado: root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01-pppoker:~# node -v
v8.10.0

Comment: e bom no caso você teria que da um purge no node e instalar novamente novamente usando o comando  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -   e depois dando sudo apt-get install -y nodejs como fala na documentação do node

Comment: pode da uma olhada em: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

Comment: Muito obrigadaaaaaaaaa Iago Carvalho.

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema porque tinha repositorio com erro, no meu caso o spotify, entretanto o comando "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
" não funcionado porque não conseguia dar um update. Eu removi o pacote do spotify e deu certo.

Answer (score -2):

Faltou uma etapa.

```
    > curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
    > sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
    > sudo apt install nodejs
    > node -v
```

Comment: Olá Davisson, a parte do `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh` e do `sudo bash` ele fez, tá no corpo da "pergunta", o problema é que o apt não estava reconhecendo o 10 mesmo assim, continuava forçando o 8, então essa suposta etapa que falta não resolve o que FOI PERGUNTADO, era problema no source.list, leia a outra resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353349/3635, pelo problema do source.list pode até ser um "bug" ou falha ocasionada por outra instalação. Obrigado pela compreensão.