# UPDATE npm e node

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou com `npm -v = 3.5.2` e `node -v = v8.10.0`
Sistema operacional: `ubuntu 18.04.`

Alguém pode me ajudar a atualizar npm e node?

Desde já agradeço, não obtive êxito após diversas pesquisas para atualização.

Comment: Sugiro utilizar nvm (node version manager), a atualização é bem tranquila, sem perder seu antigo suite de pacotes instalados da versão anterior, talvez te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388526/atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-nodejs/388543#388543

Comment: A atualização do npm é bem simples, e resume-se apenas a `npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: Deu certo para npm, obrigada
vivi@linux:~$ npm -v 6.13.7

Comment: Relacionado: [Como atualizar o Node.js da versão 8 para a 10 no Linux Ubuntu, via SSH?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349168/3774)

Answer (score 0):

Atualizei npm conforme orientação do Isac, 
e o  node foi resolvido com:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Obrigada a todos. Beijos.